# yytext accumulation problam in yacc and lex

Tags: compilation, abstract-syntax-tree, yacc, lex, preorder

I am trying to print an AST and printing an Identifier's actual name in the tree.
I am using lex and yacc.

For some reason yacc reads ahead all the tokens in a single row until ';' and this prevents me from using yytext to access an identifier's text value.

**This is the lex file:**

```
%{

%}



%%
"&&"      {return OP_AND;}
\"|"\"|"    {return OP_OR;} 
!=      {return OP_NE;}
==      {return OP_EQ;}
>       {return OP_GT;}
>=      {return OP_GE;}
\<      {return OP_LT;}
\<=     {return OP_LE;}
!       {return OP_NOT;}
=       {return ASSIGN;}
\+      {return PLUS;}
\-      {return MINUS;}
\*      {return MULT;}
\/      {return DIV;}
\&      {return ADRS;}
\^      {return PTR_VAL;}
\;  {return SEMI;}
,   {return COMMA;}
\{  {return CURLY_O;}
\}  {return CURLY_C;}
\(  {return PAREN_O;}
\)  {return PAREN_C;}
\|      {return BAR;}
\[  {return SQR_O;}
\]  {return SQR_C;}
else      {return ELSE;}
if        {return IF;}
do      {return DO;}
for        {return FOR;}
bool   {return BOOL;}
void   {return VOID;}
int { return INT;}
charp   {return CHARP;}
intp   {return INTP;}
string   {return STRING;}
while       {return WHILE;}
true      {return TRUE_;}
false     {return FALSE_;}
return    {return RETURN;}
null        {return NULL_;}



0|[1-9][0-9]*           {return CONST_INT;}

[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*           { return IDENT;}

\'.\'       {return CONST_CHAR; }
\".*\"  {return CONST_STRING; }

\[\$([^\$]*\$+[^\]])*[^\$]*\$+\]    { /*comment*/}

[ \n\t]   { /* skip whitespace */}

.     {return ILLEAGAL;}


%%
```

**This is the yacc file:**
* note that some of the rules are not completely ready but are not used by this input file and are not relevant to this case.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern char *  yytext;

typedef struct node
{
    char * token;
    struct node *b1;
    struct node *b2;
    struct node *b3;
    struct node *b4;
}node;
int yylex();
int yyerror();

struct node* mknode2(char* token,node* b1,node* b2);
struct node* mknode3(char* token,node*b1,node*b2,node*b3);
struct node* mknode4(char* token,node*b1,node*b2,node*b3,node*b4);
int printtree(node* tree);
#define YYSTYPE node*
%}


%token SEMI COMMA CURLY_O CURLY_C PAREN_O PAREN_C SQR_O SQR_C BAR
%token BOOL INT CHAR STRING INTP CHARP VOID
%token IF DO WHILE FOR RETURN
%token CONST_INT CONST_CHAR CONST_STRING NULL_ IDENT TRUE_ FALSE_
%token ILLEAGAL
%right ASSIGN 
%left  OP_OR OP_AND OP_NE OP_EQ OP_GT OP_GE OP_LT OP_LE 
%left  PLUS MINUS
%left  MULT DIV
%right OP_NOT
%right ADRS
%right PTR_VAL
%nonassoc LOWER_THAN_ELSE
%nonassoc ELSE
%start program

%%

program    : functions {printtree($1);}
           ;

functions  : functions function {$$ = mknode2("FUNC" ,$2,$1);}  
           |    {$$ = NULL;}                    
           ;

function   : type id PAREN_O f_params PAREN_C CURLY_O body CURLY_C { $$ = mknode3($1,$2,$4,$7);}
           ;

body       : var_decls stmts ret_stmt {$$ = mknode3("BODY" ,$1 , $2 , $3);}
           ;

nest_block : stmts {$$=$1;} 
       ;

f_params   : f_params_ {$$ = $1;}    
           | {$$ = NULL;}             
           ;

f_params_  : f_params_ COMMA param {$$ = mknode2("," , $3 , $1);}
           | param {$$ = $1;}
           ;

param      : type id {$$ = mknode2($1 , NULL , $2 );}     
           ;

var_decls  : var_decls var_decl { $$ = mknode2("DECL" , $2 , $1);}
          | var_decls function {$$ = mknode2("DECL" , $2 , $1);}
           | {$$ = NULL;}                       
           ;

var_decl   : type var_list SEMI { $$ = mknode2($1 , NULL , $2); }
           ;

var_list   : var_list COMMA dec_assign {$$ = mknode2(",", $3 , $1);}
           | dec_assign { $$ = $1 ;}
           ;

dec_assign : id ASSIGN expr { $$ = mknode2("=", $1 , $3);}
           | id {$$ = $1; }                      
           ;


type       : BOOL {$$ = yytexy;}        
           | INT { $$ = yytext;}        
           | CHAR {$$ = yytext;}        
           | INTP {$$ = yytext;}        
           | CHARP {$$ = yytext;}       
           | STRING {$$ = yytext;}      
           | VOID {$$ = yytext;}    
           ;



stmts      : stmts stmt { $$ = mknode2("STMT" , $2 , $1 );}     
           | { $$ = NULL ;}         
           ;

stmt       : assignment SEMI {$$ = $1 ;}                
           | fct_call   SEMI    {$$ = $1; }     
           | IF PAREN_O expr PAREN_C opt_nest   %prec LOWER_THAN_ELSE {$$ = mknode2("if" , $3 , $5 );}
           | IF PAREN_O expr PAREN_C opt_nest ELSE opt_nest {$$ = mknode3("if" , $3 ,  $5 , $7 );}          
           | WHILE PAREN_O expr PAREN_C opt_nest {$$ = mknode2("while" , $3 , $5);}
           | DO CURLY_O nest_block CURLY_C WHILE PAREN_O expr PAREN_C SEMI {$$ = mknode2("do" , $3 , $7);}
           | FOR PAREN_O assignment SEMI expr SEMI assignment PAREN_C opt_nest {$$ = mknode4("for" , $3 , $5 , $7 , $9 );}
           ;


opt_nest   : CURLY_O nest_block CURLY_C {$$ = $2;}      
           | stmt {$$ = $1;}    
           ;


ret_stmt   : RETURN expr SEMI { $$ = mknode2("return" , NULL , $2);}
        | { $$ = NULL; }    
           ;

assignment : id ASSIGN expr {$$ = mknode2("=" , $1, $3);}               
          | id SQR_O expr SQR_C ASSIGN expr {$$ = mknode3("=" , $1 , $3, $6 );}     
           ;

fct_call   : id PAREN_O expr_list PAREN_C {$$ = mknode2("FUNCALL" , $1 ,$3 );}
           ;

expr_list  : expr_list_ expr {$$ = mknode2("AGRS" , $2 , $1);}
       | {$$ = NULL;}       
       ;

expr_list_ : expr_list_ expr COMMA { $$ = mknode2("," , $2 , $1);}
       | {$$ = NULL;}       
       ;

id         : IDENT { $$ = mknode2(strdup(yytext) , NULL , NULL);}
           ;



expr       : expr PLUS expr { $$ = mknode2("+" , $1 , $3);} 
           | expr MINUS expr { $$ = mknode2("-" , $1 , $3);}
           | expr MULT expr { $$ = mknode2("*" , $1 , $3);} 
           | expr DIV expr { $$ = mknode2("/" , $1 , $3);}  
           | expr OP_AND expr { $$ = mknode2("&&" , $1 , $3);}  
           | expr OP_OR expr { $$ = mknode2("||" , $1 , $3);}
           | expr OP_NE expr { $$ = mknode2("!=" , $1 , $3);}
           | expr OP_EQ expr {$$=mknode2("==",$1,$3);}
           | expr OP_GT expr {$$=mknode2(">",$1,$3);}   
           | expr OP_GE expr {$$=mknode2(">=",$1,$3);}
           | expr OP_LT expr {$$=mknode2("<",$1,$3);}
           | expr OP_LE expr {$$=mknode2("<=",$1,$3);}
           | OP_NOT expr {$$=mknode2("!",NULL,$2);}
           | PTR_VAL expr {$$=mknode2("^",NULL,$2);}
           | ADRS expr  {$$=mknode2("&",NULL,$2);}
           | MINUS expr {$$=mknode2("-",NULL,$2);}      
           | literal {$$=mknode2($1,NULL,NULL);}
           | fct_call {$$= $1 ;}
           | id {$$= $1;}           
           | PAREN_O expr PAREN_C {$$=mknode2("(_)",NULL,$2);}  
           | BAR expr BAR {$$=mknode2("|_|",NULL,$2);}
           ;

literal    : CONST_INT {$$ = "const_int";}
           | TRUE_ { $$ = "true" ;}
           | FALSE_ { $$ = "false" ;}
           | CONST_CHAR { $$ = "const_char" ;}
           | CONST_STRING { $$ = "const_string" ;}
           | NULL_ { $$ = "null" ;}
           ;

%%
#include "lex.yy.c"
void main(){
    return yyparse();
}


int tabCount =0;

struct node* mknode2(char* token,node*b1,node*b2)
{

    node* newnode=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    char* newstr;

    if( token ){
        printf("token: %s \n" , token);
        newstr=(char*)malloc(sizeof(token)+1);
        newstr[sizeof(token)]='\0';
        strcpy(newstr,token);
    }
    else{

        newstr=(char*)malloc(3);
        strcpy(newstr,"AA");
    }

    newnode->b1=b1;
    newnode->b2=b2;
    newnode->b3=NULL;
    newnode->b4=NULL;
    newnode->token=newstr;

    return newnode;
}

struct node* mknode3(char* token,node*b1,node*b2,node*b3)
{
    node* newnode= mknode2(token,b1,b2);
    newnode->b3=b3;
    return newnode;
}

struct node* mknode4(char* token,node*b1,node*b2,node*b3,node*b4)
{
    node* newnode= mknode3(token,b1,b2,b3);
    newnode->b4=b4;
    return newnode;
}



void printTabs(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<tabCount;i++){
        printf("\t");   
    }
}


int printtree(node* tree)
{


    tabCount++;
    printTabs();
    printf("%s\n",tree->token);

    if(tree->b1)printtree(tree->b1);
    if(tree->b2)printtree(tree->b2);
    if(tree->b3)printtree(tree->b3);
    if(tree->b4)printtree(tree->b4);

    tabCount--;
    return 1;
}


int yyerror(){
    printf("ERROR!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**this is the input file:**

```
void main(int x){
    int y,w,r; int z;
}
```

**this is the output AST in preorder:**

```
FUNC
    void
        main
        int x
            x
        BODY
            DECL
                int z;
                    ;
                DECL
                    int y,w,r;
                        ,
                            ;
                            ,
                                ,
                                ,
```

**the output i expected:**

```
FUNC
    void
        main
        int
            x
        BODY
            DECL
                int
                    z
                DECL
                    int 
                        ,
                            y
                            ,
                                w
                                r
```

As can be seen when I get to the rule: type in my yacc file yytext contains the whole sentence ("int y,w,r;" instead of just "int") and when I get to the rule: id it only contain one token, that happens to be one token forward then the expected token.
- Note that in the function name and the function arguments yytext works properly. 
- I tried printing yytext from the lex file and the tokens seems to contain right values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yytext` points to the last lexeme scanned. Any other previously-saved pointer into the scanner's intrrnal buffer (such as a previous value of `yytext`) is invalid, and xannot be assumed to point at anything useful.

In a parser action, you have really very little idea what the last token scanned is. Yacc/bison generate LALR(1) parsers, where the `1` indicates "one lookahead token". That means that the parser (can) always examine the *next* token, and if it does so that is the token `yytext` will point at. Some implementations always read ahead; others, like bison, sometimes do not read ahead if the lookahead won't change parser behaviour. So which token `yytext` points at during a parser action is *unspecified* and may change in future versions or with different implementations.

Bottom line: *Never* use `yytext` in a parser action. And never pass the pointer value of `yytext` from the scanner to the parser. If you will need the string value of the token in the parser, *make a copy* of the string and pass the address of the copy to the parser through `yylval`. If you use `strdup` or similar, don't forget to `free` the copy when you no longer need it.